# MySQL Stored Procedure, Multiple SELECTs only return one row?

Tags: mysql, select, stored-procedures

I've been working on a stored procedure that runs a select statement in a loop.

When viewing results through mysqli or phpmyadmin, I only receive one row. What do I need to do to return multiple rows?

Here's a really simple example that illustrates my problem....

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS simple //
CREATE PROCEDURE simple()
BEGIN

DECLARE c INT(10);
SET c = 1;

REPEAT

  SELECT c;
  SET c = c + 1;

UNTIL c >= 10 END REPEAT;

END //
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to handle this would actually be to store your output into a temporary table, and then do a final select at the end of the while loop.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS simple //
CREATE PROCEDURE simple()
BEGIN

    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE output (finalC INT(10));

    DECLARE c INT(10);
    SET c = 1;

    REPEAT

      INSERT INTO output SELECT c;
      SET c = c + 1;

    UNTIL c >= 10 END REPEAT;

    SELECT * FROM output;

END //
```